# Вывести массив байт пользователю

Tags: php, byte, bytearray, readfile

Есть необходимость динамически сгенерировать и вывести последовательность байт (так чтобы у пользователя при переходе на страницу скачался файл).

[Пример найденного решения](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php)

Все решения которые я нашел, связаны с выводом существующего файла, однако у меня нет возможности хранить сгенерированный файл на сервере постоянно. Как я могу сгенерировать и отдать пользователю этот массив в виде файла не выделяя для него места на хостинге навсегда? Расширение файла - exe.

Comment: Почему нельзя создать файл во временной папке или с правом на запись, и удалить его после выдачи или некоторое время?

Comment: а зачем навсегда? создаете файл в temp, выгружаете. система подчистит

Answer (score 0):

@splash58 навел меня на ответ. Созданный через tmpfile файл отлично справляется с этой задачей.

```
$content = file_get_contents('file.exe') . $somedata;

$temp = tmpfile();

write($temp, $content);

fseek($temp, 0);
    
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"file.exe" . "\"");

echo fread($temp, strlen($content));

fclose($temp);
```

Comment: пардоньте, а в чем смысл сего действа? какую роль тут играет этот временный файл? почему было просто не сделать `echo $content` ? зачем этот временный файл вообще нужен7

Comment: @teran хз, в вопросе он якобы динамически генерирует этот файл

Comment: @Jean-Claude он берет `file.exe` и динамически дописывает туда `$somedata`